Gazebo robot falls over on spawn; "The published robot description file (urdf) seems not to be genuine"
In my gazebo simulation my robot fails to maintain itself. It falls over in the spawn and starts to vibrate by itself. There were multiple terminal errors. While fixing these errors, I sometimes cause another problem:
The published robot description file (urdf) seems not to be genuine

I don't always get this error. Sometimes I do, sometimes I don't.

What causing my urdf file to be not genuine?
Why is my robot falling over spawn? I know that many reasons for this are not having proper controllers which I fixed it in my recent post with Gazebo_ros2_control library, not having proper damping and friction values, not having proper inertia values and not having a proper PID gains. If there are more reasons I want to know and how can I also add PID gains to my project. For now I will only add my urdf file but if you suspect from anything let me know.

My urdf file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from octobot.xacro                  | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="octobot">
  <material name="silver">
    <color rgba="0.700 0.700 0.700 1.000"/>
  </material>
  <transmission name="doner12_tran">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="doner12">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="doner12_actr">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="doner23_tran">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="doner23">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="doner23_actr">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="doner34_tran">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="doner34">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="doner34_actr">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="doner45_tran">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="doner45">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="doner45_actr">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="doner56_tran">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="doner56">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="doner56_actr">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="doner67_tran">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="doner67">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="doner67_actr">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <parameters>/home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_config/config/ros2_controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    <gravity>true</gravity>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Motor2Gv_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Motor3Gv_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Motor4Gv_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Motor5Gv_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Motor6Gv_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Motor7Gv_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Silver</material>
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  </gazebo>
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.01104339129651807 -5.25334719245186e-08 0.09293988490750445"/>
      <mass value="17.613743236958385"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.087346" ixy="-0.0" ixz="0.000413" iyy="0.099484" iyz="0.0" izz="0.061677"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="Motor2Gv_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0073547207227992635 -5.7183835097550754e-08 0.13244866550568501"/>
      <mass value="14.13180132167806"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.05358" ixy="-0.0" ixz="-0.002639" iyy="0.052304" iyz="0.0" izz="0.029049"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0 -0.0 -0.174"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor2Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0 -0.0 -0.174"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor2Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="Motor3Gv_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.040302427728824475 -3.1776755710503087e-08 0.14852969258891868"/>
      <mass value="9.34356309497989"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.04708" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.012293" iyy="0.053199" iyz="-0.0" izz="0.020547"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.059 0.0 -0.326"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor3Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.059 0.0 -0.326"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor3Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="Motor4Gv_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0030612425184283498 -3.0946477218760627e-06 0.1067843579424047"/>
      <mass value="8.873874448445003"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.023613" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.000801" iyy="0.023432" iyz="1e-06" izz="0.012203"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.5455"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor4Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.5455"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor4Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="Motor5Gv_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.02928590541122761 2.9599701849593294e-05 0.14797355123897027"/>
      <mass value="9.684238619334375"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.049575" ixy="-7e-06" ixz="-0.012451" iyy="0.056529" iyz="-1.3e-05" izz="0.021122"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0495 5e-05 -0.6725"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor5Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0495 5e-05 -0.6725"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor5Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="Motor6Gv_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0011632770512901751 1.17570137097191e-06 0.09112293887057576"/>
      <mass value="6.164349978605796"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.013483" ixy="-1e-06" ixz="-0.000289" iyy="0.013993" iyz="-0.0" izz="0.00637"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 -0.0 -0.8933"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor6Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 -0.0 -0.8933"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor6Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="Motor7Gv_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.02716716791682726 -2.753113110725478e-05 0.09747913986651802"/>
      <mass value="5.870034266249876"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.014009" ixy="-3e-06" ixz="0.003344" iyy="0.016521" iyz="3e-06" izz="0.008501"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0435 -4.4e-05 -1.0093"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor7Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0435 -4.4e-05 -1.0093"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/dogukanyilmaz/ws_octobot/src/cores/octobot_description/meshes/Motor7Gv_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="world"></link>
  <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="doner12" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.174"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="Motor2Gv_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 -0.0 -1.0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="doner23" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.059 -0.0 0.152"/>
    <parent link="Motor2Gv_1"/>
    <child link="Motor3Gv_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
    <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="doner34" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.059 0.0 0.2195"/>
    <parent link="Motor3Gv_1"/>
    <child link="Motor4Gv_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 -1.0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="doner45" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0495 -5e-05 0.127"/>
    <parent link="Motor4Gv_1"/>
    <child link="Motor5Gv_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
    <axis xyz="0.999999 0.001011 0.0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="doner56" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0495 5e-05 0.2208"/>
    <parent link="Motor5Gv_1"/>
    <child link="Motor6Gv_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 -0.0 -1.0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="doner67" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0435 4.4e-05 0.116"/>
    <parent link="Motor6Gv_1"/>
    <child link="Motor7Gv_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
    <axis xyz="-0.999999 -0.001011 0.0"/>
  </joint>
    <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
      <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
      </hardware>
      <joint name="doner12">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial value">0.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="doner23">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial value">0.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="doner34">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial value">0.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="doner45">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial value">0.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="doner56">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial value">0.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="doner67">
        <command_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="position">
          <param name="initial value">0.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
    </ros2_control>
</robot>


can you add the full log please?

and add also the ROS distro you are using

@ChristophFroehlich I am using iron, I stopped getting the error but falling problem continiues and according to this log, controllers do indeed properly load. Here is the full log: [link] (https://pastebin.com/eEUJy0vc) Edit: I fixed the link and paste issue

what do you mean by falling down? as if the motors have no power, or "exploding"? The latter is typical for wrong inertia/mass values.

joint_trajectory_controller should hold the position on activation. And you use position interface, this should be ideal in gazebo_ros2_control without the need for any PID tuning.

I have an arm controller in my moveit_controllers.yaml file which is generated by Moveit2_setup_assistant. Also easier way to explain the falling should be video so the link: https://youtu.be/5bH-n5UTitk

It looks like that you just have commanded a pose which is having a collision with the ground. what is the status of the joint_trajectory_controller? Your posted log says "active", is this the case? Introspect the controller_state topic, what is the reference value and what the feedback one?

Yes its load_joint_state_controller = ExecuteProcess(cmd=['ros2','control','load_controller','--set-state','active','joint_state_broadcaster'], output='screen') . However I am not sure how I can introspect the topic? Should I use ros2 topic echo?

yes, use ros2 topic echo or GUI tools like plotjuggler or foxglove

and you posted the python launch code, but not the status of your controller. See ros2controlcli, e.g. ros2 control list_controllers.

Here: joint_state_broadcaster[joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster] active     arm_controller      [joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController] active    both of them are active

Apperently you and @McQueenPC was right. I added a launch argument to my spawner that spawns higher in the z dirrection which solved the falling. Its just I need to adjust the distance so that its not noticable. So problem was indeed contact of the first link and the ground. I am closing the topic thanks for everything.

@ChristophFroehlich hi sir, I was trying to transfer my project into ROS Noetic dist and I have some problems with moveit task constructor package. Could you help me out to figure out what is the problem in this question?

I have no experience with ROS, sorry.

I have had a robot fall over when spawning because it was spawning in the ground. I am not sure that is the case here but making sure it spawns a centimeter above the ground has fixed this issue for me.

So should add something like this to my first link after dummy world link? ' '

I have always done it by doing this:
gazebo_spawner = Node( package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py', output='screen', arguments=["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", "robot", '-z', LaunchConfiguration('z_pos')])
and
DeclareLaunchArgument('z_pos', default_value='1.6'),

Solved the problem thanks for everything. I have a new error but atleast it worked :D


A robot might fall over if the controller could not be loaded properly.
The URDF error can happen if you have configured joints which are not included in your URDF, see the release notes here (only applies if you use Jazzy or Rolling).
gazebo_ros2_contol does not support transmissions, which you have added in your URDF.


Transmissions are auto-generated by ros2. I created this urdf file from xacro file which was obtained after the conversion from fusion. I commented the transmission part didnt not change anything.

ROS 2 does not auto-generate anything. You mean the moveit2 wizard?
However, ros2_control does not use this information anyways, so it was expected to not change anything.

I used the command xacro model.xacro > model.urdf However you are right about the auto-generate. I am not sure what converts it.

xacro only does evaluate your xacro commands, but does not auto-add the transmissions.

Yes sorry what mean is that generated from this exporter: https://github.com/syuntoku14/fusion2urdf
